# WebSocket: Unable to receive message at client end

Tags: javascript, php, ratchet

I am using **Rachet** and trying the JS code given [here](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world). Upon the running following code in my Chrome's Console Window, I can't see any message. `conn.send()` says undefined:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

**Update**

Code at Server End:

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                print "Someone else is here";
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $msg = ' Server responds:- '.$msg;
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

See Client and Server in Action
[image]

**Update #2**

It seems following check is the problem:

```
if ($from !== $client) {}
```

But upon removing that it is broadcasting to all connect clients rather to the one who sent message

Comment: can you share your php code? specifically where you store/keep the connected clients?

Comment: @brense it's here `Chat` class http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Comment: alright, in the chat-server window do you see your client connect? `New connection! xxx`

Comment: @brense I updated the question with screenshot along with code at server end on getting message.

Comment: did you try logging just `e` and not `e.data`? It looks like everything on the server-side is working as it should. Also you have to connect another client because your current code wont send the message to the client that send it.

Comment: @brense I found the issue and added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the issue was this line at server end:

```
if ($from !== $client) {}
```

It was not letting server to respond to respective client and was going to respond if it is *Not* that client. I just changed it to:

```
if ($from === $client) {}
```

And it worked for me. The `!==` given in example code was for a typical chat application where one client will talk to other while in my case it will only be a `Server <->Client`

Comment: You can also remove the if statement alltogether so the message will be sent to all clients regardless if they were the sender or not

Answer (score 0):

@Volatil3, you could probably try out my package https://github.com/php-pure/sacky-server and https://github.com/php-pure/sacky-client

I have a class interpreter that handles `channel` base, same with socket.io

In sacky-server, execute on your console `/tests/run`, then in sacky-client, open 2 browser tabs located at `channel/channel.html`.